# How redux thunk payloadCreator callback function without parameters should be handled?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

My app needs to fetch settings in startup. It doesn't need any parameters because it fetches everything. There haven't been issue before adding

```
rejectWithValue
```

so that actual status or error can be shown to users. However it needs 2 parameters so I did it like this:

```js
export const fetchClientSettings = createAsyncThunk(
  'app-settings/fetch-client-settings', 
  async (_notUsed = undefined, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL);
      if (!response.ok) {
        return rejectWithValue(new Error(response.statusText));
      }
      return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

I'd like to know how this is done the correct way. For some reason the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) doesn't mention this case. Only how to handle more than 1 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason the documentation doesn't mention this case. Only how
> to handle more than 1 parameters.

That is because this is more a Javascript "thing" than it is a Redux & Redux-Toolkit "thing". There's a fair amount of assumption that developers have familiarity with the language.

Redux-Toolkit created actions ***always*** take *up to* a single argument, e.g. the action payload. `createAsyncThunk` actions are no different in this regard. The payload creators are passed two arguments, the value that is to be the action payload, and the `thunkApi` that allows the asynchronous action access to the store instance and various utilities.

If you didn't pass any argument, and didn't need to access the `thunkAPI` in the second arg, the code could simply look like the following:

```js
export const myAsyncAction = createAsyncThunk(
  'async/myAsyncAction', 
  async () => {
    ...
    return /* something */;
  }
);
```

```js
dispatch(myAsyncAction());
```

In Javascript if a function takes multiple arguments that don't necessarily all need to have defined values, they ***must*** still be declared in the function declaration. Any valid [Javascript identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) will work here, but a common practice is to use the underscore `"_"` character for these unused function parameters/arguments. You could also use it with a more descriptive name if there was more than 1 unused argument, e.g. `"_unused_arg_1"`. In other words, whatever works for you or your team is fine. If you are not passing a value for the payload, you still need to declare an identifier so you can "skip" it to get to the second argument that you *do* need to access.

```js
export const myAsyncAction = createAsyncThunk(
  'async/myAsyncAction', 
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      // ... happy path logic
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      // ... sad path logic
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

```js
dispatch(myAsyncAction());
```

Just for information, if you needed to pass *more than* 1 argument to an `createAsyncThunk` action you'd pack it into a single object as the first argument to the payload.

Example:

```js
export const myAsyncAction = createAsyncThunk(
  'async/myAsyncAction', 
  async (arg, thunkApi) => {
    const { foo, bar } = arg;
    try {
      // ... happy path logic
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      // ... sad path logic
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

```js
dispatch(myAsyncAction({ foo: "foo", bar: "bar" }));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I've never had situation like this. I put optional method arguments as last. Never as 1st. So I am familiar with TS, this kind of situation just has never arised. As you see from my example I already solved it with an argument starting with underscrore. It just felt wrong.

Comment: @charm Yes, it is undefined by default, but that doesn't matter if you aren't using it anyway, as you say.